# Typescript: Highcharts not accepting series unless it is individually added

Tags: typescript, highcharts, quasar

I have been trying to render Data inside my chart using Highcharts but for whatever reason is is not accepting the parameters I send to addSeries method. I tried adding 'series as an array of objects. i tried adding one at a time with 'forEach' and the method bellow but it doesnt work and i always get this error

```
*Argument of type '{ name: string; type: string; color: string; data: number[]; stack: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SeriesOptionsType'.
  Type '{ name: string; type: string; color: string; data: number[]; stack: string; }' is not assignable to type 'SeriesXrangeOptions'.
    Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
      Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'XrangePointOptionsObject[]'.
        Type 'number' has no properties in common with type 'XrangePointOptionsObject'.Vetur(2345)
let series: {
    name: string;
    type: string;
    color: string;
    data: number[];
    stack: string;
}[]*
```

this is the entire code of my chart. it is rendered in a div with the corresponding id

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting'

Exporting(Highcharts)
let series = [
  {
  name: 'Name 1',
  type: 'bar',
  color: '#4E868E',
  data: [5,6],
  stack: 'hello'
  },
  {
  name: 'Nam2',
  type: 'bar',
  color: '#4E868E',
  data: [1,2],
  stack: 'hello'
  }
]
export default defineComponent({
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    const chart = Highcharts.chart('newChart', {
      chart: {
        type: 'bar'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Test chart'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Cat1', 'Cat2]
      },
      yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: 'Results'
        }
      },
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          stacking: 'hello',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
          }
        }
      }
    })
    let i = 0;
    for( ; i < 4; i++ ) {
      console.log()
        chart.addSeries( series[i], false );
    }
    chart.addSeries(series[5]);
  }
})
</script>
```

It only works if I do 'charts.addCHarts' multiple times in a row with each series being an object of it's own outside of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can add new series by assigning data to them in the following way.

```
  this.chartOptions.series[1] = asyncData;
  this.chartOptions.series[2] = asyncData1;
```

Notice you didn't load chartOptions, and the addSeries option is used to add a single series.
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#configure

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series

```
<template>
  <div>
    <highcharts
      :options="chartOptions"
      ref="lineCharts"
      :constructor-type="stockChart"
    ></highcharts>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Chart } from "highcharts-vue";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import exportingInit from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
import stockInit from "highcharts/modules/stock";

import { EventBus } from "./../event-bus.js";

stockInit(Highcharts);
exportingInit(Highcharts);

const asyncData = {
  name: "Tokyo",
  marker: {
    symbol: "square",
  },
  data: [
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
  ],
};

const asyncData1 = {
  name: "Tokyo1",
  marker: {
    symbol: "square",
  },
  data: [
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
  ],
};

export default {
  props: {
    partsdata: {
      type: Array,
    },
  },

  components: {
    highcharts: Chart,
  },

  created() {
    EventBus.$on("btn-clicked", (data) => {
      this.chartOptions.series[0].data = data.newData;
    });
    EventBus.$on("btn-load", () => {
      this.chartOptions.series[1] = asyncData;
      this.chartOptions.series[2] = asyncData1;
    });
  },

  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          type: "spline",
          title: "Hassaan",
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: [
            "Jan",
            "Feb",
            "Mar",
            "Apr",
            "May",
            "Jun",
            "Jul",
            "Aug",
            "Sep",
            "Oct",
            "Nov",
            "Dec",
          ],
        },
        tooltip: {
          crosshairs: true,
          shared: true,
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        plotOptions: {
          spline: {
            marker: {
              radius: 4,
              lineColor: "#666666",
              lineWidth: 1,
            },
          },
        },
        series: [
          {
            data: [1, 2, 3],
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-forked-fwo68?file=/src/components/Chart.vue

Comment: alright, i'll try this out in a bit.

Comment: sorry but this didn't work. I am getting the error :
Type '{ name: string; type: string; color: string; data: number[]; stack: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Series': chart, index, options, points, and 28 more.

Comment: Please show me this in the demo, I will check it.

Comment: https://codepen.io/user-test/pen/oNeXyze

Comment: I don't see this error after fire up your demo, looking again at what you wrote above it is possible you just need to add the missing type. This article explain how to extending Highcharts in TypeScript https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/highcharts-typescript-declarations#solving-problems

Comment: but type is added within the series

Comment: Sometimes this is not enough and TypeScript requests a type completion, you can use any type or try to assign missing types.